# Goldengate warning on table with primary key

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, goldengate

Installed Goldengate Version 18.1.0.0.0 for Oracle 11gR2. Table has primary key and yet goldengate complains that there is no key found,see below

```
    GGSCI (server01.localdomain as gguser@UPGR) 3> add trandata scott.books

    2019-01-23 22:44:42  WARNING OGG-06439  No unique key is defined for table BOOKS. All viable columns will be used to represent the key, but may not guarantee uniqueness. KEYCOLS may be used to define the key.

    2019-01-23 22:44:42  INFO    OGG-15130  No key found for table SCOTT.BOOKS.  All viable columns will be logged.

    2019-01-23 22:44:42  INFO    OGG-15135  TRANDATA for instantiation CSN has been added on table SCOTT.BOOKS` 

    GGSCI (server01.localdomain as gguser@UPGR) 10> info trandata scott.books

    Logging of supplemental redo log data is enabled for table SCOTT.BOOKS.
Columns supplementally logged for table SCOTT.BOOKS: "AUTHOR", "ID", "LANGUAGE_ID", "TITLE", "YEAR_PUBLISHED".

Prepared CSN for table SCOTT.BOOKS: 978016
```

This is DDL of scott.books from Oracle SQL Developer

```
CREATE TABLE "SCOTT"."BOOKS" 
   ("ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "TITLE" VARCHAR2(26 BYTE), 
    "AUTHOR" VARCHAR2(23 BYTE), 
    "YEAR_PUBLISHED" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "LANGUAGE_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
     CONSTRAINT "PK_ID" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
  )
```

Can someone point me in right direction.
Thanks

From dba_constraints

```
SQL> SELECT
  2      constraint_name,
  3      constraint_type,
  4      status,
  5      validated
  6  FROM
  7      dba_constraints
  8  WHERE
  9      owner = 'SCOTT'
 10      AND table_name = 'BOOKS';
CONSTRAINT_NAME                C STATUS   VALIDATED
------------------------------ - -------- -------------
PK_ID                          P ENABLED  VALIDATED
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it's a bug but logging out ggsci session twice did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the PK exists, but it is not enabled or not validated. Make sure the PK is enabled and validated, then try adding trandata again.